# dnsmasq: Give own DHCP client higher priority?

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp

I would like to use dnsmasq and pihole to create a DHCP server which propagates the DNS server to the clients.

I already did it with IPv4: I disabled the DHCP in the router, setup DHCP in dnsmasq and let it distribute the DNS address. And it works: All devices don't have advertisment.

**But I have a big problem:** I am using a very bad router (Speedport Smart by Telekom) where DHCPv6 cannot be deactivated!
My clients won't listen to dnsmasq, because the DHCPv6 reply of the router comes a few microseconds faster than the answer from my Raspberry... (I checked it with Wireshark)
And because devices usually prefer IPv6, I still have advertisment, as long as I don't disable IPv6 ... but this is not possible without a rooted Android.

**So my question is:** Can I somehow make the clients ignore the DHCP response of my router and force them to automatically use my raspberry's response? (Somehow, give my response a higher priority than the router's?)
Or is it at least possible to give the clients an additional list of DNS addresses which has a higher priority?

So the clients would have this DNS list:

> 2003:xxxx:xxxx....  (<-- DNS address from the DHCP response of my
>   raspberry, with higher priority) fe80::1 (<-- DNS address from the
>   DHCP response of my router)

My current configuration of dnsmasq is:

```
[11:59]root@ras3:/etc/dnsmasq.d$ cat 99-dhcp.conf 
enable-ra
ra-param=high,60
no-hosts
no-resolv
dhcp-authoritative

### IPv4
dhcp-option=1,255.255.255.0
dhcp-option=3,192.168.69.1
dhcp-range=192.168.69.200,192.168.69.250,72h
dhcp-option=252,"\n"
dhcp-option=option:ntp-server,129.6.15.27
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,192.168.69.60

### IPv6
dhcp-range=::100,::1ff,constructor:eth0
dhcp-option=option6:information-refresh-time,1h
dhcp-option=option6:ntp-server,[2610:20:6F15:15::27]
dhcp-option=option6:dns-server,[fe80::3da:f98:b225:5e4],[2001:4860:4860::8888],[2001:4860:4860::8844]

## Clients
dhcp-host=24:77:03:68:DB:5C,dell_wlan,192.168.69.89
dhcp-host=88:AD:D2:95:F6:D8,galaxy_a5,192.168.69.113

## DNSSec
dnssec
trust-anchor=.,19036,8,2,49AAC11D7B6F6446702E54A1607371607A1A41855200FD2CE1CDDE32F24E8FB5
dnssec-check-unsigned
```

Comment: Perhaps you could change the DNS settings on your router.

Comment: @DanielB Unfortunately, I can only change the IPv4 DNS directly at the router. The IPv6 DNS can't be changed there.

Comment: I see. In that case, what you want cannot be accomplished. You need to change your network layout. Depending on whether the Telekom router can support IPv6 Prefix Delegation or you’re willing to incur the performance issue of bridged firewalling, you may have to give up on IPv6 though.